# Minimizing the energy in a ruler

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to find the shape a metal ruler takes when it is forced into certain specific boundary conditions.

## Introduction

Imagine a long thin metal ruler, that is forced to bend around a number of nails that are nailed into a sheet of wood. The ruler will take on a certain shape to minimize its internal deformation energy.

The smaller the radius of curvature along the length $l$ of the ruler, the more energy is needed to force it into that shape. If $\theta$ is the angle that the ruler makes with the horizontal, we want to minimize its change, i.e., we want to minimize $$E = \int_0^L \left|\frac{d\theta}{dl}\right| dl = \int_0^X \left|\frac{d\theta}{dx}\right| dx.$$ Using $g(x)$ to describe the path of the ruler, we see that $\theta(x) = \arctan(g'(x))$. The change in the angle is therefore
$$ \frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+g'(x)^2} g''(x). $$
So: whatever the boundary conditions, we want to find the function $g(x)$, so that $$E = \int_0^X \left|\frac{1}{1+g'(x)^2} g''(x)\right| dx$$ is minimal.

Now, without boundary conditions, this is trivial: due to the absolute value signs, the absolute minimum is $E=0$, which is obtained when $g''(x)=0 \forall x\in[0,X]$, i.e., when $g(x)$ is a straight line. Which is what's expected: the ruler is straight if there are no additional conditions it needs to fulfil.

It becomes more interesting with boundary conditions.

## Boundary conditions

- The most natural boundary conditions, in line with how I initially presented the problem, is that there are several points $(a_i, y_i)$, and the condition is that, for all $i$, $$g(a_i) = y_i$$ This is an interesting problem, and already one I couldn't solve.
- For reasons I won't go into here (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814150/approximate-piecewise-constant-function-with-continuous-function) if you're interested), the problem I'm *actually* trying to solve is one where there is a boundary condition on the *integral* of $g$. There are several tuples $(a_i, b_i, y_i)$, and the condition is that, for all $i$, we have $$\int_{a_i}^{b_i} g(x) dx = y_i \cdot (b_i-a_i)$$ I have no idea how to go about this, and would be grateful for any tips.

Many thanks!

---

EDIT:

Now, I'm not sure if it's actually helpful, but, solving the integral for E, we get

$$ \begin{align} E &= \int_0^X \left|\frac{1}{1+g'(x)^2} g''(x)\right| dx \\ 
&= \int_{I_+} \frac{1}{1+g'(x)^2} g''(x) dx + \int_{I_-} \frac{1}{1+g'(x)^2} (- g''(x)) dx \\
&= \left. \arctan(g'(x)) \right\vert_{I_+} - \left. \arctan(g'(x)) \right\vert_{I_-} \end{align} $$
With $I_+$ and $I_-$ the $x$-intervals where $g''(x)$ is positive and negative, respectively.

Because $I_+$ and $I_-$ form a continuous interval from $0$ to $X$, we can also write this as
$$
E = \arctan(g'(X)) - \arctan(g'(0)) - \left. 2 \arctan(g'(x)) \right\vert_{I_-}  
$$
Our goal is to find the function $g(x)$ that minimizes this expression while conforming to the boundary conditions.

Comment: [Strain Energy & Deformation][1]             is an example from Mechanics. If slope is large, ode  becomes non-linear. May be simple problem of only three nails for a start should be asked.

  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzULLcCJtqU

Answer (score 2):

Euler-Bernoulli Law defines a linear relation with a proportionality constant ( flexural rigidity EI) between curvature (whose arc integrand is the slope $ \theta$ you mention) and the Bending Moment (blue).

Nails at black dot points (deformation) in plywood eventually define forces using well developed approaches of Mechanics of Materials / Strength of Materials starting 18th century...on materials like a fiberglass bar or elastic metal ruler. At these fixed points (called simply supported or hinged )the bending moment vanishes.

A simple program listing in `Mathematica` is given where at simple support arc lengths $ (s=-2,s=-1,s=1) $ the moments vanish. Integration is done by `NDSolve` using Runge-Kutta numerical integration algorithms.

[image]

The NDSolve numerically integrates automatically from second to first (slope) derivative and next to $ [x(s),y(s)], \dfrac{dx}{ds}= \cos \theta,\;\dfrac{dy}{ds}= \sin \theta,\;$ and the shape of curve of deflection is seen.

```
EI=3;smin=-2;smax=1.5;
bm[s_]= -EI (s-1)(s+1)(s+2)/3;
BdgMoment=Plot[bm[s],{s,smin,smax},PlotStyle->{Thick,Blue},GridLines->Automatic,AspectRatio->0.6]
equn={PH'[s]==bm[s]/EI,X'[s]==Cos[PH[s]],Y'[s]== Sin[PH[s]],PH[0]==0.5,X[smin]==-2,Y[smin]==2};
NDSolve[equn,{PH,X,Y},{s,smin,smax}];
{ph[u_],x[u_],y[u_]}={PH[u],X[u],Y[u]}/.First[%];
deflection=ParametricPlot[ {x[s],y[s]},{s,smin,smax+.4},PlotStyle->{Red,Thick},GridLines->Automatic,AspectRatio->0.4 ]
```

Static equilibrium shapes come about automatically by energy minimization of elastic strain energy stored $ U=\int \frac{M^2}{2 EI} ds$.  A set of forces can be found that produce a moment distribution of the first figure.

[image]

By action of the forces (omitted here), the (blue) bending moments come about. These moments determine curvatures from point to point. So by such direct integration an *Elastica* (Euler) type shape (red) can be arrived at as shown. I have included three nails  but they can be generalized to  arbitrary numbers and positions.

For *small* rotations a solution of elastic curve (aka "beam") due to Prof. Hetényi / MIT reminds one  of the Maclaurin's series:

$$ y(x) = y_0 + y'_0(x) +-y''(0) \frac{x^2}{2!}- y'''(0)\dfrac{x^3}{3!}..$$

where the third and fourth derivatives  represent bending moment and shear force upto the constant EI.

Your approach that virtual work/energy decides shape of elastic rulers is basically correct. However, the *forces* need to be brought in. There are *theorems of Castiliagno* that link energy ( its partial derivative with respect to *forces* ) to determine the deformation/shape.

I am sure my answer creates  more questions but in view of the range of details involved, that is about the best I could present for now.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer; a few follow-ups if I may: (a) I'm having a hard time parsing the `Mathematica` snippet, but it seems you're using a solver to minimize the energy, just - where is the integration defined? Solving the equations analytically is not an option? (b) Is there a way to include my second set of boundary conditions?

Comment: (a) I have replaced the screen grab to Latex for convenience. Integration is inside the NDSolve.Solving the integration with two nails is possible with Elastica , having two supports. This can be googled, involves Elliptic Integrals. With more pivots/hinges/nails it becomes more complicated and in such situations engineers prefer numerical methods (b) The equilibrium equations involve rotations by integration and initial/ boundary conditions inclusively define unique solutions.